# APIGEE : How to do step by step Class-based dynamic Quota

Tags: apigee, quota

I would like to enable the API quota per user in APIGEE. I had been trying to get some steps on that, i got very few information in APIGEE site as Class-based dynamic Quota.
Could you please provide step by step procedure to enable the quota per user policy as in Class-based dynamic Quota?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify a user specific variable in your Quota Policy.  If you're using OAuth, you can set an Attribute in the Generate Token policy like this

```
<OAuthV2 async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="OAuth-Gen-Token">
    <DisplayName>OAuth Gen Token</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Attributes> 
    <Attribute name="userid" ref="request.formparam.login" display="false"/>
  </Attributes>
  <Operation>GenerateAccessToken</Operation>
    <ExpiresIn>86400000</ExpiresIn>
    <SupportedGrantTypes>
      <GrantType>password</GrantType>
    </SupportedGrantTypes>
    <GrantType>request.formparam.grant_type</GrantType>
       <UserName>request.formparam.login</UserName>
     <PassWord>request.formparam.login</PassWord>
     <Scope>request.formparam.scope</Scope>
  <GenerateResponse/>
</OAuthV2>
```

Where the <Attribute name="userid" ref="request.formparam.login" display="false" /> becomes a unique variable for that user. It will be populated when you Verify the Access token as a variable named accesstoken.userid

Then define your quota using that variable like this:

```
<Quota async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Quota">
    <DisplayName>Quota</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Identifier ref="accesstoken.userid"/> 
    <Allow count="2000" countRef="apiproduct.developer.quota.limit"/>
    <Interval ref="apiproduct.developer.quota.interval">30</Interval>
    <Distributed>true</Distributed>
    <Synchronous>false</Synchronous>
    <TimeUnit ref="apiproduct.developer.quota.timeunit">minute</TimeUnit>
    <AsynchronousConfiguration>
        <SyncIntervalInSeconds>20</SyncIntervalInSeconds>
        <SyncMessageCount>5</SyncMessageCount>
    </AsynchronousConfiguration>
</Quota>
```

Your quota will then increment on the <Identifier ref="accesstoken.userid" /> which should be unique it each user.

Comment: I have a doubt, is it possible to apply this using API keys instead of OAuth? If yes, could you please mention the solution how to set Class-based dynamic Quota with API keys. Thanks,

Comment: I have a question.  If you're using app level keys how can you identify individuals?  IP address? Something in headers or payloads?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, as you say, we cannot pass the user id authentication in app level keys. I am just thinking loudly, can I send the id as one of the keys while calling the API URL by appending the query parameters

Comment: You can then set that variable as your Quota Indentifier like -Identifier ref="request.queryparam.yourparam"- or if doing client_credentials grant, set it as an access token attribute and use that attribute as your Identifier

Answer (score 0):

```
I have created OAuth parameters as suggested. Then i got a error in API console as follows to retrieve token:
ErrorCode: invalid_request",Error:Required param : grant_type.
I think, we have give values for this parameters in API console
 <GrantType>request.formparam.grant_type</GrantType>
       <UserName>request.formparam.login</UserName>
     <PassWord>request.formparam.login</PassWord>
     <Scope>request.formparam.scope</Scope>
  <GenerateResponse/>
How to pass value for UserName, Password and Scope values as there are chile elements for Granttype parent element.
```